# Entity Framework 6 wrong reference when update model from database

Tags: entity-framework-6, updatemodel

After uptade Entity framework any version to Entity Framework in existing project 
in MYDATABASE.edmx When I update model from database Visual studio generates using lines such as

```
  using System.Data.Objects;   
  using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
```

but Here is should be:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Open MYDATABASE.Context.tt (Your code generation template) (Under the MYDATABASE.edmx)

2.Find invalid references like this

> ```
> {
> #>
> using System.Data.Objects;   
> using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
> using System.Linq;
> <#
> }
> ```

3.Replace like this

> ```
> {
> #>
> using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
> using System.Linq;
> <#
> }
> ```